# Performing an XSLT transformation on part of an XML document selected with DOMXPath

Tags: php, xml, xslt, content-management-system

Okay this is driving me nuts. I am trying to make a simple CMS using an XML file and some PHP. I have an XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sections>
<section name="about">
    <maintext>
        <p>Here is some maintext. </p>
    </maintext>
</section>
<section name="james">
    <maintext>
        <p>Zippidy do.</p>
    </maintext>
</section>
</sections>
```

Then is the XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="section">
<div class="section">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</div>  
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="maintext">
<xsl:copy-of select="child::node()" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transformation works fine - I get a couple of simple paragraphs:

```
<p>Here is some maintext. </p>      
<p>Zippidy do.</p>
```

However, I now have a PHP file which should query the XML, take a specific "section" according to its GET parameter. And then run the transformation on just that part of the XML, echoing the result.

```
<?php

$sectionName = $_GET["section"];
$content = new DOMDocument();
$content->load("content.xml");
$transformation = new DOMDocument();
$transformation->load("transform-content.xsl");
$processor = new XSLTProcessor();
$processor->importStyleSheet($transformation);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($content);
$sectionXML = $xpath->query("section[@name='".$sectionName."']")->item(0);

echo $processor->transformToXML($sectionXML);
?>
```

Trouble is that whatever I do the whole XML file is transformed, not just the section I've selected with the query. What am I doing wrong here?!

Comment: `transformToXML` expects a `DOMDocument` parameter, not an arbitrary node. Does it work if you use `transformToDoc` instead?

Comment: Or failing that, create a new empty document, [import](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) and [append](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php) the section element to that, then transform it.

Comment: TransforToDoc didn't work but using the import and append approach worked perfectly - thanks for the help! It's odd though that in my original code that transformToXML went ahead and transformed the original XML document when it had just been given the node from the path query. Why not just throw an error for having been given the wrong type? Oh well ... problem solved anyway!  :)

Comment: At a guess it was taking the ownerDocument of the node and transforming that. Anyway, glad it helped, and I've made my comments into an answer you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transformToXML` requires a `DOMDocument`, not just any node. I guess what it's doing in your current code is transforming the "owner document" of the node you pass it.

Try creating a new document, then use `$newDoc->appendChild($newDoc->importNode($sectionXML, true))` to attach the existing element to the new document, then transform this document instead of the original one.